# Correct img path with vue2 and gh-pages

Tags: path, vuejs2, github-pages, vue-cli

Using

```
"vue": "^2.6.8" 
"webpack": "^3.6.0",
"webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
"webpack-cli": "^3.2.3",
"webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.7",
"webpack-merge": "^4.2.1"
```

I have tried several options to get the correct path for an image in a vue project to work in gh-pages.

```
.div-bg
    {
        background-image: url("../assets/previewImages/SAD-1.jpg");
        height: 570px;
        width: 1020px;
    }
.div-bg1
    {
        background-image: url("/src/assets/previewImages/SAD-1.jpg");
        height: 570px;
        width: 1020px;
    }
.div-bg2
    {
        background-image: url("~/src/assets/previewImages/SAD-1.jpg");
        height: 570px;
        width: 1020px;
    }
.div-bg3
    {
        background-image: url("/assets/previewImages/SAD-1.jpg");
        height: 570px;
        width: 1020px;
    }
.div-bg4
    {
        background-image: url("~/assets/previewImages/SAD-1.jpg");
        height: 570px;
        width: 1020px;
    }
/* .div-bg5
    {*/
        /* background-image: url("../assets/previewImages/test.jpg");*/
      /*  background-image: url("@/assets/previewImages/SAD-1.jpg");
        height: 570px;
        width: 1020px;
    } */
```

But none of them are working.

I tried @/assets/previewImages/SAD-1.jpg but this gives errors when compiling.

Also I have looked at various [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29359754/git-not-pushing-correctly-for-github-gh-pages) but to no avail.

This project is pushed to gh-pages using

```
$ npm run build 
$ sudo vcg
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you try ./assets/..  ???

Comment: Thanks I hadn't tried that but did just now and just saving the file after that change gives an error. Vue must not be able to find a file on that path. thanks for your suggestion